# Update Nested Attributes with Composite Primary Keys Returns Unpermitted Parameters Error with Rails 4.1x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, transactions, composite-primary-key

I have an edit form being sent to rails via a JSON feed. This form has two levels of nested attributes, with the last level using a composite primary key. Here's a typical params:

```
Parameters: {"project"=>{"name"=>"Yes We Can", "topics_attributes"=>{"65"=>
  {"name"=>"Obama", "feed_size"=>500, "topic_sources_attributes"=>{"65,twitter"=>
  {"platform"=>"twitter", "keywords"=>"Obama"}}}}}, "id"=>"19"}
```

As mentioned, the topic_sources_attributes uses composite keys, such as [65, twitter]. This hasn't been an issue with creating new projects, but when I try to run an update it returns a unpermitted params error, closing the transaction and not updating any attributes.

```
Project Load (9.2ms)  SELECT  `projects`.* FROM `projects`  WHERE `projects`.`id` = 19 LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: 65,twitter
(9.0ms)  BEGIN
Topic Load (9.9ms)  SELECT `topics`.* FROM `topics`  WHERE `topics`.`project_id` = 19
TopicSource Load (9.7ms)  SELECT `topic_sources`.* FROM `topic_sources`  WHERE `topic_sources`.`topic_id` = 65
(9.1ms)  COMMIT
Completed 204 No Content in 72ms (ActiveRecord: 57.3ms)
```

Typically, when saving nested attributes I've just made sure to include the id as a permitted param:

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, topics_attributes: [:id, :name, :feed_size, topic_sources_attributes: [:id, :topic_id, :platform, :keywords]])
end
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be sufficient. Does anyone know how to correctly set params so that this transaction can update correctly?

Comment: What is your form view? It looks like you have something funky going on there which is causing `65, twitter` to be passed like it is. Doesn't seem to be a well formed JSON for creating/updating a model.

Comment: The form view is a dynamically generated via an Angular.js form. It can accept either an object or an array to render data but when submitting data using an array it doesn't recognize that a key already exists and tries to insert a new database row, resulting in a duplicate entry error.